# Adapter that converges two API sources into one model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Let's say I have a JSON API where I can access two models: `cats` and `dogs`. However, on my Ember application I only have one model: `animals`.

Although every time I `save()` an `animal`, it's POSTed to the API as a `cat`, if I receive a `dog` linked in any other model it should be locally stored as an `animal` by ember-data.

What would be the most coherent way to achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. For future reference, it is possible to create an alias to a model, extending the ApplicationSerializer (in this case, our model is `animal`, and although it had an adapter that used the `cat` model in the API, the `dog` model needed to be parsed as an `animal` as well):

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({
  typeForRoot: function(root) {
    if (root == 'dog' || root == 'dogs') { root = 'animal'; }
    return this._super(root);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve what you want by customizing the REST adapter. Specifically, look into [overriding the `buildURL` method](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.14.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L532) to detect the type of the record passed and to construct the URL to be passed based on logic that determines whether this particular model should be persisted to the `cats` endpoint or `dogs` endpoint.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't solve the problem. If I receive a `dog` element in the `links` section of the JSON API reply, it won't be parsed as an `animal` model, no matter what `buildURL()` does. Thank you for your input, though!

Comment: Do you have control over the API or are you using thrid party APIs?

Comment: I have control over the API (although it's in use by third parties, so it would be desirable to leave it as is, and tackle the issue on the client).

Comment: Figured it out, @Oren. Thank you for your help :).